# Use Core Data when rewriting an App in Swift from Obj C

Tags: objective-c, swift, core-data

I have a version of an App currently on the App Store which I have written in Objective C. It stores data using Core Data. I have been working on improvements and have decided to write the next iteration of the app using Swift.

Having completely changed the feel of the app and using Swift to do the hard work, is it possible to have it use the Core Data already in place when Users update the app? Or will they have to start again and lose the data they already have? Will the updated App be considered as a new App?

Can I just "drop the Swift code" into the original Obj C project and then delete the Obj C Code and hope it will work? Is there a migration which can happen between the two versions? The Core Data is primarily the same between versions.

Thanks in advance for any assistance you can give.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Core Data uses SQLite, binary or XML (OSX only) files to persist data, so it does not matter in what language your app is written in.

Comment: To add to this answer, Core Data works in both Swift and Objective-C.  You can use either language (or both).

Comment: I think my question was badly written. But thanks for your responses.